# Скрыть блок если сняты чекбоксы

Tags: javascript, jquery

По умолчанию при открытии страницы чекбоксы сняты, как сделать что когда мы снимаем выделение с чекбоксов страница перезагружалась бы или скрывался нужный div?

Делаю через window.location.reload(); но соответственно страница уходит в постоянный релоад, т.к. изначально они сняты.

Comment: я одна не понимаю вот этого: "По умолчанию чекбоксы сняты, как сделать что когда мы снимаем выделение с чекбоксов..."? о.о

Comment: Вешайте событие на $(".checkbox").change() а не на $(window).load()

Comment: Спасибо решил через $('.serv_radio').change(function(){}